# PHP Field Entry On Change With Apostrophe

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following form where when the user selects an option from the `<select>` the javascript enters it into the "name" field.  It's working perfectly except when the option contains an apostrophe it truncates it to only before the apostrophe.  I've tried adding the `selectedValue = selectedValue.replace(/'/g, \"\\'\");` to the javascript but it is not helping.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```html
#related form objects
echo "<br><br>Name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" id=\"name\" value=\"$name\" size=\"50\">";

  echo "<br>Nearby Suggestions: <select name='nearby' id='nearby'>"; $places=file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='.$lat.','.$long.'&key=xxx&radius=80');
  $output= json_decode($places,true);
  foreach($output['results'] as $place){
    echo "<option value='$place[name]'>$place[name]</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";


  #script to enter nearby field into name field upon selection
  echo "
<script>$(document).on('change','#nearby',function(){
    var x = document.getElementById(\"nearby\"),
    selectedValue = x.value;
    selectedValue = selectedValue.replace(/'/g, \"\\'\");
    $('input[name=name]').val(selectedValue);
    });</script>";
```

Comment: Probably won't resolve your issue but you should ALWAYS wrap strings in quotes in PHP.  `$place[name]` is invalid.  It should always be `$place['name']` or `$place["name"]`.  Use concatenation when necessary: `"<option value='" . $place['name'] . "'>"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't escaping the values that come from your googleapis call.  So when you blindly load a value like `Jim's Place` into your `<option>` tag, the resulting code is:

```
<option value='Jim's Place'>Jim's Place</option>
```

which contains 3 apostrophes and is broken.  Convert the values first.

```
foreach($output['results'] as $place){
  $place_converted = htmlspecialchars($place['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
  echo "<option value='$place_converted'>$place_converted</option>
}
```

which correctly generates:

```
<option value='Jim&#039;s Place'>Jim&#039;s Place</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and great explanation.  Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value='$place[name]'>$place[name]</option>";
```

results in mismatched quotes.  Try replacing it with

```
echo "<option value=\"$place[name]\">$place[name]</option>";
```

You can escape your double quotes that wrap the value.